# Flutter can't connect to Rails API only properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, flutter, dart, ruby-on-rails-5.2

Ok guys, here is my problem.

I have a standard Rails 5 API only setup.

My user controller is pretty much standard one:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[show update destroy]

  # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all

    render json: @users
  end

  # GET /users/1
  def show
    render json: @user
  end

  # POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)


    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
      UserNotifierMailer.send_signup_email(@user).deliver      
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      render json: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password, :email)
  end
end
```

Now when I post data to the server from Postman it works flawlessly, and it registers the user just fine.

Here is what I have from Postman:
[image: Screenshot]

On the other hand, I'm using the Flutter application, and I'm trying to register.

Here is Flutter model.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class HeadUser {
  User _user;

  HeadUser({User user}) {
    this._user = user;
  }

  HeadUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    _user = json['user'] != null ? new User.fromJson(json['user']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this._user != null) {
      data['user'] = this._user.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class User {
  String _username;
  String _email;
  String _password;
  int _id;
  DateTime _createdAt;
  DateTime _updatedAt;

  User({int id, DateTime createdAt, DateTime updatedAt, String username, String email, String password}) {
    this._username = username;
    this._email = email;
    this._password = password;
    this._id = id;
    this._createdAt = createdAt;
    this._updatedAt = updatedAt;
  }

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
    id: json['id'],
    username: json['username'],
    email: json['email'],
    createdAt: json['created_at'],
    updatedAt: json['updated_at'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['username'] = this._username;
    data['email'] = this._email;
    data['password'] = this._password;
    return data;
  }
}

Future<HeadUser> loginUser(String url, {Map body}) async {
  return http.post(url, body: body).then((http.Response response) {
    final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || statusCode == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while posting data");
    }
    return HeadUser.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  });

}
```

And my call for this one looks like:

```
 onPressed: () async {
                          if (_formKey.currentState.validate())
                          {
                            HeadUser usr = new HeadUser(user: User(
                              email: this.emailEditingController.text.trim(),
                              password: this.passwordEditingController.text.trim(),
                              username: this.usernameEditingController.text.trim()
                            ));


                            HeadUser response = await loginUser(REGISTRATION_URL, body: usr.toJson());
```

But when I do that, I get an error in my Flutter application like I'm having a "user" parameter missing, though when I print it out it shows the exact structure, but I get this. 
[image: screenshot 2]

In this case, request is not even fired, so the server doesn't get hit.

However if I try to do `json.encode(body)` in a `loginUser` method, then my response from server is:

[image: screenshot 3]

And of course Flutter complains:

[image: screenshot 4]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The params Rails receives must be in the form `{ user: {  id: ..., name: ... } }`, what you're sending now is probably like `{ id: ..., name: ... }`.

Comment: @SebastianPalma thank you for the tip. It wasn't the issue, but the request headers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I actually found a problem (and a solution).

For some weird reason, Rails requires the data to be posted explicitly as a "Content-type": "application/json".

So it's also needed to set the request headers, and pass them into the `http.post` method.

```
Future<HeadUser> loginUser(String url, {Map body}) async {
  Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"};
  return http.post(url, headers: headers, body: json.encode(body)).then((http.Response response) {
    final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || statusCode == null) {
      throw new Exception("Error while posting data");
    }
    return HeadUser.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  });
```

Comment: I have seen many response, but this header things was the issue! thanks after 7 hours, I got your response and solved issue.